# nested loops and increment user input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to print user input numbers and indent them by that number of spaces. I can't seem to get the numbers to indent, however, I am able to print them all vertically. Any help? Here is my code.

```
 for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          System.out.println(i);
          break;
```

If a user entered the number 3, my output would currently look like this:

```
1
2
3
```

When it should look like this:

```
   1
    2
     3
```

Comment: Where is the code to indent?

Comment: Your inner loop should not print a new line, it should simply print a space for each iteration, then your outerloop should print the integer value and a new line

Comment: Where are your closing parentheses? If that `break` is inside your inner for loop, then it's only happening once for each value no matter what.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Could you post the exact wanted output?

Comment: thanks @Kon. That worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add another for loop within that for loop. The print statement would be after this nested for loop. The inner loop would start from zero to i+1. In this for loop, you can print the spaces or tabs. Then after the for loop you can print the number. Make sure you do not include a new line inside the print statement in the inner for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the code yet to add the indenting. Try this:

```
public static void printNum(int userNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(userNum+ "\n");
}
```

Calling it with:

```
printNum(10);
printNum(1);
printNum(2);
printNum(3);
```

Gives the following:

```
run:
          10
 1
  2
   3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: This is fine; this gives the OP enough of a building block to work with.  Not bad.

Comment: @gla3dr Fixed the tab issue with space before you made the comment. Also, I provided a method to be called. OP can easily create a loop and call it. I wasn't here to give OP the complete answer ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 3; // or your userNum
        // this loop will iterates through 1 to i (or 1 to userNum for you)
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            // this loop iterates until j2 equals j (e.g. if j = 5, this loop will iterates 4 times)
            for (int j2 = 1; j2 < j; j2++) {
                // prints the space(s)
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            // prints the current number (in the first loop) and line break
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know when you've added them and I may reconsider my opinion, then.

Comment: @Makoto I added them. I hope it'll help the community.

Comment: It'd be better if you actually *explained* what was going on rather than bury the remarks in code comments.  Talking through the concepts is far more useful than seeing a smattering of code.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not as good as you are. I'd appreciate if you could give me some tips :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104343/discussion-between-stilleur-and-makoto).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem :

```
for (i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
      System.out.format("%+(i-1)+s]%n", i);
```